# How to disable image tag when image is not loaded or API returned path is not valid in Angular4

Tags: html, angular

I am working in an Angular Application,In this application I am using images.Image path is getting from database through API .

When a user clicked on a product the product name is passed to the API and the Images related to the product is get as response .In my application I have maximum of five images for a specific product.

If I hover on the images it will display the big size image of it.

My HTML

```
<div class="row">
      <img id="sm001" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)"  src="{{smallImages['0']['small_Images']}}" alt="img1" class="img-thumbnail" [attr.ref]="bigImages['0']['big_Images']">
      <img id="sm005" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)"  src="{{smallImages['1']['small_Images']}}" alt="img2" class="img-thumbnail" [attr.ref]="bigImages['1']['big_Images']">
      <img id="sm002" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)"  src="{{smallImages['2']['small_Images']}}" alt="img3" class="img-thumbnail" [attr.ref]="bigImages['2']['big_Images']">
      <img id="sm003" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)"  src="{{smallImages['3']['small_Images']}}" alt="img4" class="img-thumbnail" [attr.ref]="bigImages['3']['big_Images']">
      <img id="sm004" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)"  src="{{smallImages['4']['small_Images']}}" alt="img5" class="img-thumbnail" [attr.ref]="bigImages['4']['big_Images']">
  </div>
```

What I want to do is ...

1, If the API returns only 3 images(max is 5) ,I want to hide the remaining 2 img tags (I don't want to show any alt tag contents just want totally disable the img tag).

2,if the API returned image path is not(not present in assets folder )loaded in img tag ,I want to disable that img tag.(empty or null or " " or undefined).

is it possible please guide me to solve this . Thanks

Comment: Based on condition check you can maintain Boolean value and we can take condition like this <img *ngIf="isEnabled">

Answer (score 1):

In regards to issue 1:

```
<div *ngFor="let image of smallImages">
   <img [src]="image.small_Images" (mouseenter)="...">
</div>
```

The `ngFor` gives you access to the `let <value>` within that. This makes it automatically add the amount of images as are available in the array.

In regards to issue 2:

This is a little bit more difficult because this means you will have to preload the images.

You can lookup some ways to do this but I think you're talking two very different issues here, so normally you would turn it into two different questions.

In regards to an easy (JavaScript in TypeScript) way of preloading images:

```
const img = new Image(); 
img.onload = () => {
    console.log('Images is loaded and exists!');
}
img.onerror = () => {
    console.log('Image could not be loaded for whatever reason.');
}
img.src = 'blabla'
```

Of course you will need to figure out how to run this code on your results. So you're talking a big difference between component logic and template logic; therefore: This should be a different issue and a different StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than controlling the image display purely in HTML, you should be using "ngFor" to loop through the set of images returned by a query against your API, something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <ng-template *ngFor="let image of images">
    <img id="{{image.id}}" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter($event)"  src="{{image.url_small}}" alt="{{image.alt}}" class="img-thumbnail" [attr.ref]="{{image.url_big}}">
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

You would then construct the `images` array as a property of your controller in your Typescript code when you process the results of the API that returns you the image data.

The "Tour of Heroes" covers this on their page about displaying data, [here](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data).

I could provide a more focused answer if you provided more details of the API you're making your requests against, and the actual code that is making those requests, but hopefully you can take it from here.